# Bool function to check if a word is in an array C++

Tags: arrays, boolean, compare

I'm working on some code check if word is in ignoreWords array. The function keeps returning true for the first value and then false for the rest of the elements even if some of the words are in the ignoreWords array. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, I'd appreciate any help or advice.

```
bool isIgnoreWord(string word, string ignoreWords[])
{
    int length; 
    string copy[length];
    for(int i=0; i < length; i++){
        copy[length] = ignoreWords[i]; //to find out length of ignoreWords
        //cout << copy[length] << endl;
        if(copy[length] == word)
            return true;
            else
            return false;
                 
        
        
       
    }
    
    //function returns whether word is in the ignoreWords array
}
```

edit: fixed it. I made it so much more complicated than it really is. This is the code that works:

```
bool isIgnoreWord(string word, string ignoreWords[])
{
    for(int i=0; i < 50; i++){
        if(ignoreWords[i] == word){
            return true;
        }
        
    }
    return false;
    //function returns whether word is in the ignoreWords array
}
```

Comment: How can you have copy[length] if you haven't initialised length?

Comment: I actually was confused about that. I wanted to initialize length since I'm not explicitly told how long the length is... my solution was to copy length to ignore words to find out the length. Pretty sure that's a lousy way to do it though

Comment: Also please give a minimal reproducible example. BTW You use Variable Length Arrays which is C only, not standard C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would be because your if-else statement in the for loop returns in both conditions.

Imagine you're the computer, and you start the for loop:

```
if (copy[length] == word) {
    return true;
}
else {
    return false;
}
```

So you get to the first element in the array, and let's say it doesn't match the word you're checking against. This if-else statement says to return false if it's not, and immediately stops the function because a return statement was found.

What you probably want is for your program to only return false if it exits the for-loop without finding any matches, e.g.

```
for (...) {
    if (matches) return true;
}

return false;
```

Another thing to note is that you're not initializing `length` before using it in a statement, *and* initializing a variable-length array like that isn't supported on all compilers.

Comment: Thank you for your response. What if I want to return true twice? Like if I find two or three words that are words we're supposed to ignore? I don't want my function to return the first true and then leave out the rest.

Comment: You should always treat return statements as the definite end of a function; I can't think of a single language that allows you to return more than once. If you want to collect all the strings that match the given value, I might suggest returning an array or vector - a `return` statement can only ever happen once.